# Annoyingly Wide Left Gutter In IntelliJ 15

Tags: java, intellij-15

I see something in IntelliJ 15 that I've never seen before, and I don't know how to make it stop.

The left gutter, where breakpoints, line numbers, version control annotations, etc. are rendered, is several inches wide in my upgraded IntelliJ 15.  The bottom scroll bar stops at the border as well.  I can't find anything in general settings to make it stop.

Is this a new "feature" in IntelliJ 15?  Can anyone tell me how to tell the IDE to go back to a rational width and stop wasting all my screen space?

Comment: Could you post an image? Have you tried a reinstallation?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see that effect with 15.0.3 Community edition on Gentoo Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bug has been filed for this exact situation: [IDEA-148002](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148002):

> The left border is too wide, find no option to make it thinner.

This affects version 15 of IntelliJ IDEA (143.381). As for now, there are no fix version and no comments, so it looks like you will have to wait for that bug to be taken into account...

---

This change is probably due to the addition of new buttons inside the gutter, as mentioned in the [release notes](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/06/intellij-idea-15-eap-is-open/):

> #### Running Applications via Gutter Icon
>
> Now you can set up a Run/Debug configuration for any class (that has a main method) and launch it with just one click

Comment: I couldn't remember my JetBrains account password, so I couldn't search bug database myself.  As usual, SO to the rescue.  Thank you for bringing it to my attention.  Hopefully JetBrains will address it soon.